# Rsync wont delete files from an external drive

Tags: rsync

Can someone please tell me why the following command does not delete the extra files on backup2Drive.

Backup1Folder is a folder and backup2Drive is a drive.

```
rsync -avh --exclude '._*' --delete /Volumes/ext/Backup1Folder/ /Volumes/backup2Drive
```

Answer (score 0):

you are either missing `--delete-excluded` or you are skipping the delete step because of previous i/o errors